# Error while installing Oracle 12c database on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, oracle, database

I followed this tutorial to install Oracle database 12c in Ubuntu 16.04

http://tutorialforlinux.com/2016/03/31/how-to-install-oracle-12c-database-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-64bit-easy-guide/

However I am getting the following error on executing the command

```
/tmp/database/runInstaller

Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
>>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/bin/xdpyinfo.
Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    
Failed <<<<

Some requirement checks failed. You must fulfill these requirements before continuing with the installation,
```

What to do now?

UPDATE:

I did:

```
DISPLAY=hostname:0.0
export DISPLAY
xclock
```

source:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/895904?tstart=0

Now I get the following error:

```
Error: Can't open display: [myhostname]:0.0
```

UPDATE:

My error is probably because X server is most likely not listening on a TCP socket.

Source:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/display%3D-0-0-vs-display%3Dlocalhost-0-0-a-933940/

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to edit the lightdm.conf file

Do:

```
vim /etc/init/lightdm.conf
```

and add the lines

```
xserver-allow-tcp=true
xserver-command=X -listen tcp
```

Then reboot the system

The errors can now safely be ignored.